# How to pull out three numeric characters in a string?

Tags: string, vba

I have a long list of names in Excel that all contain "PP" followed by a number. e.g. `PP10` or `P101.`

I would like to pull out the numbers after 'PP'. I have tried the following code but it only seems to work up to `PP99`, anything with three numeric characters after "PP" does not read properly.

```
For n = 1 To MyCount

    If Mid(MyString, n, 2) = "PP" Then

        If IsNumeric(Mid(MyString, n + 2, 1)) Then

            PP_Image = Mid(MyString, n + 1, 3)

        End If
    End If
Next n


If IsNumeric(Mid(PP_Image, 2, 2)) Then

    PP_Image = Mid(PP_Image, 2, 2)

Else: IsNumeric (Mid(PP_Image, 2, 1))

    PP_Image = Mid(PP_Image, 2, 1)

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your indices. If `Mid(MyString, n, 2) = "PP"` and `IsNumeric(Mid(MyString, n + 2, 1)) = True` then `Mid(MyString, n + 1, 3)` will give you "Pxx", and leave off the last number. Which will then make your later checks and conversions be off. Change the assignment of `PP_Image` to

```
PP_Image = Mid(MyString, n + 2, 3)
```

note the n + 2, to keep in line with the previous search for "PP"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
Function PP_Image(ByVal MyString As String) As Double

    Dim lPosition As Long

    lPosition = InStr(1, MyString, "PP", vbTextCompare)
    Select Case (lPosition > 0)
        Case True:  PP_Image = --Trim(Left(Replace(MyString, " ", String(99, " "), lPosition + 2), 99))
        Case Else:  PP_Image = 0
    End Select

End Function

Sub tst()

    Dim varString As Variant

    For Each varString In Array("Example PP10", "Example PP101")
        MsgBox PP_Image(varString) ' => 10, 101
    Next varString

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have reasons why it doesn't work, but check out the Split() function. Something like

```
PP_Image = Val(Split(MyString, "PP")(1))
```

would give the numerical answer of anything in the name after "PP".

See [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for more info on Split().

Comment: This is assuming there is no additional text beyond the PP#.  If the text was something like "Example OO11 PP222 QQ3456" then this method would not provide correct results

Comment: However, if the text terminates after the PP# as shown in the asker's examples, then the Split method will work perfectly.

Comment: The examples provided above were all "Example PP#". The work around for this would be a double split: `PP_Image = Val(Split(Split(MyString, "PP")(1), " ")(0))`

That is, assuming there's a space after the number.

Comment: Yes, the double split would cover all bases. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Tester()
    Debug.Print PPMatch("sdhgs sh s PP22 ggg")
    Debug.Print PPMatch("sdhgs sh s PPs66 ggg")
    Debug.Print PPMatch("sdhgs sh s PP555555 ggg")
    Debug.Print PPMatch("sdhgs sh s PP0 ggg")    
End Sub


Function PPMatch(txt As String)
Dim re As Object, matches, match

    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    re.Pattern = "PP(\d+)"
    re.ignorecase = False
    re.Global = True
    Set matches = re.Execute(txt)
    If matches.Count > 0 Then
        PPMatch = matches(0).submatches(0)
    Else
        PPMatch = ""
    End If
End Function
```